# R plot in ascending order

Tags: r, sorting, plot

Is there a way to sort a R plot(x,y) in ascending order?
I sorted my data frame to look like this: `sortuncharted <- uncharted[order(uncharted$V2),]`

> name = sortuncharted$V1
>
> averages = sortuncharted$V2

Even though my table is sorted,

> plot(name,averages)

doesn't come up sorted.
This is what my table looks like:

```
    8825        WNT10B_121975.2341   0.0000000   0
    8906                grp_1.1021   0.0000000   0
    1598        CREBBP_147639.3240   0.1911765   0
    8845         WNT3_161926.10289   0.1948718   0
    3533       HOXA13_76141.2.5002   0.2253521   0
    3621          HSPG2_3089.11773   0.2432432   0
```

but my plot is all over the place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that name is not an ordered factor. When plotting, R orders the data based on the ordering of the factor levels. You need to reorder the leves:

```
sortuncharted$V1 <- reorder(sortuncharted$V1, new.order = sortuncharted$V1)
```

Another option is to make it an ordered factor like this ( but you will get different output from regression operations and probably will not understand that output since it will create polynomial contrasts.):

```
sortuncharted$V1 <- factor(sortuncharted$V1, levels = sortuncharted$V1, ordered = TRUE)
```

Also try to provide a smaller example that can be reproduced if this doesn't help.

Comment: -1. You do NOT need to make it an ordered factor. The key is to sort the levels, which plotting and regression functions will then handle as you expect. (Will reverse the downvote when you correct.)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that. I left the creating ordered factor as an alternative.

Comment: It wasn't fixed so I took you comment as permission to fix it.